# Why IntelliJ IDEA Maven doesn't execute my Tests?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, build, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running `install` on IntelliJ IDEA and this is the output that I get:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.myaddress.webapp.TestWebApp
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

As you can see, there are 0 tests run. I don't have any "skip tests" button activated.

This is the full console output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Webservices\webapp "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=38581:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.3.1 install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building aws-lambda 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Webservices\webapp\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Webservices\webapp\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Webservices\webapp\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Webservices\webapp\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Webservices\webapp\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.myaddress.webapp.TestWebApp
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ aws-lambda ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Webservices\webapp\target\webapp.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Including com.myaddress.webapp:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-CR2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.symphonia:lambda-logging:jar:1.0.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:jar:1.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-jersey:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-core:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.9.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.27 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b42 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing C:\Webservices\webapp\target\webapp.jar with C:\Webservices\webapp\target\webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Webservices\webapp\target\webapp.jar to C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\com\myaddress\webapp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Webservices\webapp\pom.xml to C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\com\myaddress\webapp\1.0-SNAPSHOT\webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.524 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-07T17:28:23-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/319M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not very much experienced with Maven, so what's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us TestWebApp class containing test methods?